# I want to show if the delivery is late

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a delivery tab which will display all Purchase Order that haven't arrived yet. How do I compare a PODate Datetime field in the database to the DateTime.Now

I'm trying to use this code

```
DateTime poDate = DateTime.Parse(PODate.Text)

if ((poDate < DateTime.Now))
Panel1.Visible = "true";
```

Can it be done using select query, that will allow me to select all those Purchase Order that are late from the database

Comment: You'll have to convert `PODate.Text` to a DateTime. How to do so is explained in plenty of places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert convert `PODate.Text` to a DateTime

```
 DateTime PODate = DateTime.ParseExact(PODate.Text, "your Date format", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


if ((poDate < DateTime.Now))
Panel1.Visible = "true";
```

**Edit**
In `select` Query where `@poDate` as InputParameter

```
select * 
from Test_Table
where 
@poDate < GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse the variable via [`DateTime.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method,

```
DateTime poDate = DateTime.Parse(PODate.Text)

if ((poDate < DateTime.Now))
Panel1.Visible = "true";
```

or use [`Convert.ToDateTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
PODate = PODate.Text

if ((Convert.ToDateTime(PODate) < DateTime.Now))
Panel1.Visible = "true";
```

But please use google next time.

Comment: @gamered123 What do you mean? can you edit your question for more detailed info?